# how to compare two objects in generic implementation?

Tags: java, generics

I have a **generic** class which will be `Long`, `Float`, `Integer` and `String` types. In the cases of `Number` (`Long`, `Float` and `Integer`), I want to **compare** two of them to see which one is bigger or smaller. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible with a moderately complex Comparator implementation and liberal use of the 'instanceof' keyword.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comment: Where in the provided link is your answer? I couldn't really find the solution there

Comment: @Seppl Not sure how much more I can help you.  The OP wanted compare two user defined classes in a GT/LT manner and I linked to the Comparator interface. The OP could use a Comparator.... to compare. Was there something more specific that you were wondering about?

Comment: Ah ok, it sounded to me as if there was a more detailed answer in the link provided, that's why I thought it must be missing @claymore1977

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way would be to implement the `Comparable` interface in your subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need that for numbers, just compare them as "values" with the same data type (the proper methods for this are provided by the `java.lang.Number` class). So you can do:

```
Double.compare( number1.doubleValue(), number2.doubleValue() )
```

where `number1` and `number2` are different types of numbers.

The `Comparable` interface is implemented by all the numeric primitive wrappers but they can only compare numbers of the same type. For instance `Integer` implements `Comparable<Integer>`, so the `compareTo` method won't accept other numeric types.